# J-Unit 4 Checking return Type

Tags: java, junit

browsed online and could not locate how to write a test that checks the return type(String)

```
 @Test
public void testExtractText(){

    String result  = myPdf().extractText();

   Assert.assertThat();

}
```

Comment: You declare it as a string, why would expect otherwise?

Comment: Are you looking for `assertEquals()`?

Answer (score 5):

Since you're already declaring the result as a String, you can't really reach the line below if the result is not a String, and you'll fail at this point.

One option is using [`Assert#assertTrue`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.8/org/junit/Assert.html#assertTrue(boolean)):

```
assertTrue(myPdf().extractText() instanceof String);
```

If you're looking for checking the **value** and not the type, then you should use [`Assert#assertEquals`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.8/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)):

```
assertEquals("expected", result);
```